# Ipod Library access -- Musicplayer not notify

Tags: ipod

i want to play songs form my application when user select song which is list out in the table view .i successfully list out songs from my iphone itunes to my application but when i select any song it only play song which is play currently in iphone.i apply notification then also it not change the song.so what i have to do to solve this problem.
i am using MPMusicPlayerController and settheQuerywithCollections with MediaItemCollections

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have turned on "Repeat One Song" function.

If you have correctly set PlaybackQueue, try fixing the repeating problem.